# Add a url inside a string by php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string

```
$string = '<a href="a.php">a</a>,<a href="b.php">b</a>';
```

I want to add url http://www.example.com before after href=" , that means it will be `<a href="http://www.example.com/a.php">`

I have tried other functions like str_ireplace  , str_replace . I want to do it by php preg_match()

I can do easily by jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.scroller a').each(function(){
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var newUrl = 'www.example.com' +url;
    jQuery(this).attr('href', newUrl);
});
jQuery('.scroller img').each(function(){
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    var newUrl = 'www.example.com' +url;
    jQuery(this).attr('src', newUrl);
});</script>
```

Can any one help me to do it by php?

Comment: Any specific reason for `preg_match()`? To the downvoters: Looks like a valid question to me!

Comment: I have tried other functions , so I think preg_match() will do it perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You looking for this:

```
$strink = "http://www.example.com";
<a href="'.$string.'a.php"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `preg_match()`, try this:

```
preg_replace ('/href=\"/', '$0http://www.example.com/', $string);
```

I'm not sure about the second argument, tough. Might need some escaping...
See here for some examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/it/function.str-replace.php) :

```
$string = '<a href="a.php">';
$url = 'href="http://www.example.com/';    
echo str_replace('href="', $url, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string is already defined somewhere else (for example: from a database), a simple way is `str_ireplace` (case-insensitive str_replace):

```
$string = '<a href="a.php">';
$string = str_ireplace('href="', 'href="http://www.example.com/', $string);
```

I'm using a string that I know exists `href="` and replacing it with `href="http://www.example.com/`